# The ring $R_{p}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

Let p be a prime number in $\mathbb{Z}$. Let $R_{p}$ be the ring $R_{p} : = \{x \in \mathbb{Q} : ord_{p}(x) \geq 0\}$. Show that x is a unit of R if and only if $ord_{p}(x)= 0$. I'm not sure how to show the converse, any hints?

Comment: This is a consequence of the fact that $ord_p : \Bbb{Q}^* \to \Bbb{Z}$ is a group homomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in Q$, $x=p^a(b/c)$ where $b,c$ are relatively prime with $p$. $ord_p(x)=a$. If $ord_p(x)=0$, $x=b/c$ and $c/b\in R_p$ is its inverse. If $a>0$, $x^{-1}$ is not in $R_p$.